# UICollectionView fully loaded callback method

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I am looking for some callback method which should be called after the `UICollectionView` is fully loaded. I know that there is no built in callback method.
But is there some alternate good way of doing this. 
I am making a custom `View` which contains a `UICollectionView` as a subView so some way of doing it inside `UIView` subclass will be great other wise you can also suggest something on `UIViewController`.

Thanks

Comment: what you mean for "fully" loaded? that you can see all cells? is there any conditions about "all" cells visibility?

Comment: All the DataSource call back methods were already called and all UICollectionViewCells are fully loaded.

Comment: There is never fully loaded scenario for collectionView/tableView. It's data may be loaded fully but not the collectionView.

Comment: a `UICollectionViewCell` is rendered only if is going to be visualized, otherwise it will not be rendered, so for this reason I asked you if you have only a few number of cells, so you are sure that they are ALL rendered

Comment: Well i mean all the cells that can be visible at a time, when those are visible.